Directional derivatives in the complex plane as a vector space.
Consider the directional derivative in the direction $v\in V$ on some vector space $V$
\begin{equation}
f_v'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}.\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over itself as a field, and then choose a simple function, e.g. $g(z)=z$. Then
\begin{equation}
g_v'(z)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{z+hv-z}{h}=v
\end{equation}
for any $v\in \mathbb{C}$.
On the other hand, with complex differentiation defined as
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+ h) - f(x)}{h},\qquad(2)
\end{equation}
we have $g'(z)=1$. So complex differentiation looks the same as the directional derivative when $v=1$ only.
Now in principle, these are two different definitions, so they don't necessarily need to agree. But on the other hand, I don't see why they are different.
Our general vector space $V$ must be a complete normed vector space to be able to discuss limits. What is the structure we need for the complex differentiation? Again, to discuss limits, we need some kind of norm (the absolute value I imagine). Is this correct? Or is there a weaker structure in the second case?
If the structures are the same in both cases, then can I understand it as follows: (1) is a valid definition for directional derivatives even when $V=\mathbb{C}$, but it is just not something that is particularly useful when $V=\mathbb{C}$. On the other hand, (2) is not a general definition for arbitrary vector spaces $V$, but is in some cases (such as $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $V=\mathbb{C}$), and is particularly useful for $V=\mathbb{C}$.

Is this  the correct idea? Or is something different going on?
